# Which One Do I Download For Sqlite Phxsoftware

Tags: c#, sqlite

As you know I am very new to this whole programming stuff.
I want to use SQLite wrapper by http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/
But there is a 100% Managed version and The Setup version.
So which one do I download exactly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're developing on Windows, the standard install (currently) would be to use [this download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/SQLite%20for%20ADO.NET%202.0/1.0.65.0/SQLite-1.0.65.0-setup.exe/download).

This is the full setup version of SQLite with the .NET 2.0 wrappers.